# not getting anything in form.parse in formidable while using express.urlencoded() as parser

Tags: node.js, express, parsing, formidable

I am tyring to get the a image and some input through express in formidable.
but I am getting nothing inside `form.parse()` in case when there is `express.urlencoded()`

this is my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const port = 80;


// stuff related to express
app.use('/static', express.static('post/static'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
// parser for express


// stuff related to pug
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/post/views'))

//endpoint
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
```

though I am also receiving fields through req no matter I am using express.urlencoded or not.
but I want them to recieve through form.parse()

basic setup

```
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    const uploadfolder = path.join(__dirname, 'static/uploads')

    // parsing
    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
        console.log(files, fields);
    })

})
```

I am recieving nothing from it
but when I remove express middleware urlencoded than it is showing
`{} { myfile: 'eventaya2.png', title: 'ayush', blogspace: 'naut' }`

but still not receiving files
I dont know how in fields section myfile is coming though it should come in files section.
I thing there is someting to do with parser
someone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To receive files you have to use the `multipart/form-data` format.

formidable can handle both `multipart/form-data` and `urlencoded` format. So don't use `express.urlencoded`.

Have a look at the examples https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/tree/master/examples (with-express.js)

Comment: i have tried it without urlencoded it still is not working.